# Function in VBA performing an addition in hms and pushing results in cell showing error

Tags: excel, vba

My function:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function hmsa(h1 As Integer, m1 As Integer, s1 As Integer, h2 As Integer, m2 As Integer, s2 As Integer)

    Dim hr1, min1, sec1, hr2, min2, sec2, h, m, s As Integer
    Dim scf, mcf, hcf As Boolean
    scf = mcf = hcf = False
    hr1 = h1
    min1 = m1
    sec1 = s1
    hr2 = h2
    min2 = m2
    sec2 = s2

   Dim r, c As Single
    r = ActiveCell.Row
    c = ActiveCell.Column
    
    s = sec1 + sec2
    If s >= 60 Then
        scf = True
        s = s - 60
    Else
        scf = False
    End If
    
    
     m = min1 + min2
    If scf = True Then
       m = m + 1
    End If
    
    If m >= 60 Then
        mcf = True
        m = m - 60
    Else
        mcf = False
    End If
    
    
    h = hr1 + hr2
    If mcf = True Then
        h = h + 1
    End If
    
    If h >= 24 Then
        hcf = True
        h = h - 24
    Else
        hcf = False
    End If
    
    
 '  MsgBox "h:" & h & " m:" & m & " s:" & s, vbOKOnly, "DEBUG"
    
   printhms h, m, s, r, c
    
    
End Function
```

and the subroutine for printing the values as

```
Public Sub printhms(ByRef hr As Integer, ByRef mn As Integer, ByRef se As Integer, ByRef r As Integer, ByRefc As Integer)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c).Value = se
    
    ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c).Offset(-1, 0).Value = mn
    ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c).Offset(-2, 0).Value = hr
End Sub
```

I receive this error at function:

> Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch

Comment: Note: You have to explicitly declare the variable type for each variable in the declaration. E.g. `Dim scf, mcf, hcf As Boolean` has to be `Dim scf As Boolean, mcf As Boolean, hcf As Boolean`. Right now `scf` and `hcf` are Variant due to lack of declaring variable type. And is `ByRefc` a typo? It should be `ByRef`.

Comment: You `Dim r, c As Single` and then `printhms h, m, s, r, c` byRef as Integer.

Comment: Thanks Raymond and Waleron, appreciate your time and effort. Did the changes and executed the code, no error. However, it doesn't print the intended result. Shall work on it before coming back for assistance. Thanks again!

Comment: This "scf = mcf = hcf = False" is legal in VBA but it does not assign false to scf, mcf or hcf.  Instead what you have after the first = is a series of boolean assertions. That you might get False as an intended value for SCF is serendipity.  If you are assigning False to these variables then you need to assign each variable individually